# Traveling from US to Indonesia with a 16 hr layover in Sydney. Have carry on luggage only. Do i still need a transit visa for that layover?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, australia

Traveling from Hawaii to Indonesia with a 16 hr layover in Sydney, Australia.  I have carry-on luggage only.  Would I still need a transit visa, or will I be ok without one?

Comment: Are you an Indonesian citizen? A US citizen?

Comment: U.S. citizen, but have been living in Bali for 3 years.  Have U.S. passport.

Comment: Get an ETA then, don't bother with the Transit Visa, it will be way more useful on the long run

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Passengers from most countries are able to transit Sydney airport without requiring a visa, as long as they meet 2 main conditions.

1. Their itinerary does not require them to leave the "airside" area of the airport, and
2. Their stay is not more than 8 hours.

You actually don't meet either of these conditions.  Your stay is 16 hours, which is clearly more than the 8 hours limit.

You're also staying 16 hours, which presumably means you have an overnight stay.  Sydney airport closes each night, and it is NOT possible to stay within the "airside" part of the airport overnight.  You will need to enter Australia for this stay.

As a US citizen you don't need a transit visa to enter Australia, but instead should apply for an [ETA](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/electronic-travel-authority-601) which will allow you to enter the country for your short visit

Answer (score 2):

> Would I still need a transit visa

**Yes**

The [Transit visa (class 771)](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa) page about transit without a visa states :

> If you are from an eligible country (see eligible countries listed below) you can transit Australia on your way to a third country. You can do this without an Australian visa, provided you meet all of the following criteria:

Indonesia (as is the US) is part of the eligible countries **but** :

> have a confirmed ticket to leave Australia to travel to a third country, by aircraft **within 8 hours of arriving**

You will need a Transit Visa for that journey, if you are a US citizen, you can also avail of the [Electronic Travel Authority (Subclass 601)](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/electronic-travel-authority-601#Overview)

Comment: The ETA is *much* more straightforward than a transit visa for this, and will work just as well.